# Regex match " character

Tags: python, match

I am trying to get data using regex but just don't know how to match the character `"` in the regex. I have tried the following:

```
text = "value=1.211.1.1" 
regex ='''w+\=(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)'''
match_result = 1.211.1.1
```

However when my text is:

```
text = value=""value=1.211.1.1""
```

I am not able to get the match. I tried the following but it doesn't work. How can I determine whether the `"` character is in a given string?

```
regex = '''w+\=\"(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)\"'''
```

Comment: Your second example is not a valid assignment to `text`. Without a [mcve] that actually represents your code and inputs, it's very difficult to help.

Comment: sorry that was typo. actual string is same as first one except having starting and ending with character " in text rather than assignment only. value="1.211.1.1"

Comment: That clarifies nothing. Do you mean `text='value="1.211.1.1"'`? What does `repr(text)` show?

Comment: Yes, I mean the same. it doesn't return me anything. In the first case, i get the desired value 1.211.1.1, but in second case no value is returned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a little confusing but is this perhaps what you're after?

```
import re
s = '"value="1.211.1.1"'
m = re.match('''['\"]*\w+=['\"]?(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)['\"]*''', s)
print(m.group(1))
```

**Output**

```
1.211.1.1
```

Comment: Sorry if I was not able to explain it properly. Actually, s should be '''value="1.211.1.1"''' and  I want the result to be 1.211.1.1.   So basically " character is at start and end of digits.

Comment: @fakhir Are the start and end of that string supposed to have three `'` characters and not `"` characters?

Comment: Yes because this string is very long and it contains many " characters. So assignment needs to be the character " to be three times. This is required as per my little knowledge.  Thanks for your help

Comment: @fakhir Still a bit confused about which combination of speech marks/apostrophes are meant to appear in the string, so I made a "master" regex pattern that'll just accommodate for the whole lot of them. Does the new regex meet your requirements? If it works you can just take that as "base" and strip it down a little bit at a time if it's too excessive.

Comment: Thanks a lot, This will do the job.